# How can I pass a BLOB type data (ByteArray) through OSB(Oracle Service Bus) to DB(Table in a Data Base with BLOB type Column)

Tags: java, database, oracle, osb

I have a **Java Callout** which returns a Java **ByteArray**. I want to pass this **ByteArray** to a table in my DB which has column with **BLOB datatype** without making any modification to the ByteArray. I am using OSB 11g as middleware. So the javacallout is done in OSB and I am using a DB adapter to connect to DB and pass this value.

[image]

**FYI**

I have made some research and found that OSB stores the ByteArray with itself and sends the reference to DB but I dont want that to be done. I want to pass the BYTEARRAY as it is exactly to my DB Table.

**In simple words:-**

Pass ByteArray through OSB to BLOB type column in a table in oracle DB

I dont want these solutions(I have already tried):-
https://blogs.oracle.com/ateamsoab2b/entry/an_example_of_how_to

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, but I was using the Java Callout to do something that OSB doesn't have support for, namely a wire protocol that an adapter wasn't ever going to be written for.  I'd ask why you're using a Java Callout to do a JDBC operation, but that's probably beside the point.  In any event, if your Proxy service is a SOAP-based one, you're going to be returning this either as a `CDATA` tag with a bunch of data, a reference id that the client will make a subsequent call for (MTOM/XOP), or lastly, a Base64-encoded string in an XML tag.

What I ended up doing was something akin to XOP/MTOM support.  What documentation have you reviewed?  In my own experience, I was able to make things work based on the following documentation:

[14.20 Adding Java Callout Actions in the Console](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/osb/develop/GUID-97AB0C09-A8CF-48CD-A173-C2A568B8A2DE.htm#OSBDV2504) (explains the limited types that can be passed in, and in turn, returned **from** the java callout to your service)

If you use a reference, it'll be more likely that the client needs to request that binary separately.  That said, there's a lot of documentation about sending MTOM requests.  I don't have much experience with it.

- [MTOM using OSB and SoapUI](http://blog.darwin-it.nl/2015/06/mtom-using-soapui-and-osb.html)
- [OSB & MTOM: WHEN TO USE INCLUDE BINARY DATA BY REFERENCE OR VALUE](http://blog.darwin-it.nl/2015/07/osb-mtom-when-to-use-include-binary.html)
- [Attachment Handling in OSB](http://osb-soa.blogspot.com/2012/03/blog-post.html)
- [39.3.8 Understanding XOP/MTOM Support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/admin.1111/e15867/context.htm#OSBAG319)

Good luck to you.  I had some headaches working with OSB on manipulating these things around, but once I got my head around the Java-OSB boundary points, it was a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

Write a java code and do a java call out and convert the byte array reference to the  desired java object. It will take the reference and return you the java object that you can store in the BLOB

Comment: My java callout is returning a ByteArray which can be stored to DB Blob type. But the problem is OSB is storing the byteArray internally and giving a reference id which I dont want. I want OSB to transfer it as it is. **OSB is storing it internally and returning this**   
`<con:body>
    <con:binary-content ref="cid:-1d03e16:13364a4b441:-7fd6"/>
</con:body>`